# can't get nested JSON object with recurring name

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm quite new to JSON so the following might be a trivial problem, but I could not find any comparable question on stackoverflow, so:

I would like to get a nested JSON object like: pizza.topping.rating but when accessing it says undefined, although  can see the rating object ... when accessing pizza.rating it works fine ... does it have something to do with the "rating" being used within the object pizza several times?

is there a work around for this situation?

thank you very much for your help

ps: the object looks something like this:

```
jQuery16207381055671721697_1329849155553(
    {"pizza":
        {"Hjid":2030,
         "creator":"n0rritt",
         "pizzaTitle":"Fungi",
         "rating":
            [
                {"Hjid":2032,
                 "creator":"n0rritt",
                 "ratingText":"it's delicious"}
            ],
         "topping":
            [
                {"Hjid":2031,
                 "creator":"n0rritt",
                 "toppingText":"with fish",
                 "rating":
                     [
                         {"Hjid":2042,
                          "creator":"n0rritt",
                          "creationTime":"2012-02-21T19:08:22.896",
                          "ratingText":"good for your health"}
                     ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: I assume you have an JavaScript object, not JSON. JSON is just a textual representation and cannot be accessed with `x.y.z`. **Please post an example of the object**. `pizza.topping.rating` returning `undefined` means that `pizza.topping` does not have a property `rating`. The existence of `pizza.rating` does not imply the existence of `pizza.topping.rating`.

Comment: Can you show us your object? `JSON.stringify(pizza)`

Comment: JSON objects are an array when done properly you should be able to use pizza[0].topping[0].rating where the zeroes are the index of the array.

Comment: There shouldn't be any limitations for repeating names. Try sending `pizza` object to Firebug `console` to ensure that data is structured in a manner you're expecting...

Comment: @Diodeus: JSON includes representations for arrays and objects. `["foo"]` is an array representation, `{"foo": "bar"}` an object representation. You can have JSON without any arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pizza.topping` is an array. Therefore you must access an array index. Like so: `pizza.topping[0].rating`.

The same goes for the rest of your arrays in there.

Comment: ahh of course I see my mistake now ... thank you very much xD